# what substitute the fuse.ko as the kernel modlue in fuse 2.9

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fuse

For the purpose that i should port the fuse into other embedded linux platforms,like android,i sucessfully cross-compile the fuse project.And as i know,the fuse can only work when there is a fuse moudlue inserted into the kernel.When in the fuse 2.2.1 or the other lower versions,it will product a fuse.ko after the make.BUt,right now,i am using the fuse 2.9.0,there is no such ko output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fuse module is now into mainline kernel. You should select the "FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) support " under the Filesystems section in the kernel configuration.